# Writing a Regular expression to capture 3 lines from big text

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have an assignment which is to write only re expression to capture these three lines

```
YOUTH WRITING WORKSHOPS ACADEMIC SUPPORT
YOUTH WRESTLING CLUB SUPPORTED YOUTH WRESTLING
YOUTH WORK THERAPY PROGRAMS
```

from very big text column in a postgresql table.

I've tried a lot of code and can get them with help of postgre functions, but the assignment need them in the same order with only re.

here is the start query.

```
SELECT purpose FROM taxdata WHERE purpose ~ '^[A-Z]' ORDER BY purpose DESC LIMIT 3;
```

I tried these expressions but they partially work cause I think it only matches the first few words.

```
^[A-Z][A-Z]... W[A-Z][A-Z]
^YO... W.{,39}[ORT|ING|AMS]$
```

and others but always fail
honestly, I don't like or use re that much, so help please.

Comment: Can you just use `^(YOUTH WRITING WORKSHOPS ACADEMIC SUPPORT|YOUTH WRESTLING CLUB SUPPORTED YOUTH WRESTLING|YOUTH WORK THERAPY PROGRAMS)$` regex?

Comment: @Eugenij I did, it says too long re.

Comment: Who says? What is your final goal?

Comment: final goal is to get these three lines in that order with re using the provided query, no hard code

Answer (score 0):

Why not =>
/^YOUTH WRITING WORKSHOPS ACADEMIC SUPPORT
YOUTH WRESTLING CLUB SUPPORTED YOUTH WRESTLING
YOUTH WORK THERAPY PROGRAMS$/gm

Comment: No hard code, should only be re.
and i tried this the autograder says too long re.

Comment: Well then i think the question is to find the patern that would fit those 3 lines and nothing says that it would not fit any other lines....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the quantifier and match one of the 3 character groups at the end, you can write the quantifier like `{0,39}` and use an alternation at the end instead of a character class like `(?:ORT|ING|AMS)$`

```
SELECT purpose FROM taxdata WHERE purpose ~ '^YO... W.{0,39}(?:ORT|ING|AMS)$' ORDER BY purpose DESC LIMIT 3;
```

See a [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ou7iFZ74RAgRHzBmUgfgHQ/0)